# How contrastive loss work intuitively in siamese network

Tags: loss, siamese-neural-network

I am having issue in getting clear concept of contrastive loss used in siamese network.

Here is pytorch formula

```
torch.mean((1-label) * torch.pow(euclidean_distance, 2) +
                                      (label) * torch.pow(torch.clamp(margin - euclidean_distance, min=0.0), 2))
```

where margin=2.

If we convert this to equation format, it can be written as

```
(1-Y)*D^2 + Y* max(m-d,0)^2
```

Y=0, if both images are from same class
Y=1, if both images are from different class

What i think, if images are from same class the distance between embedding should decrease.   and if images are from different class, the distance should increase.

I am unable to map this concept to contrastive loss.

Let say, if Y is 1 and distance value is larger, the first part become zero `(1-Y)`, and second also become zero, because it should choose whether `m-d` or 0 is bigger.
So the loss is zero which does not make sense.
Can you please help me to understand this

Comment: You can use mathjax to format the mathematical formulas here. So, maybe you can format the loss function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confused about why the margin exists.

The margin exists in contrastive learning because we only want the model to output embeddings where negative samples are far from each other to a **certain extent**.

That is, we don't want the model to train itself to output embeddings where the distance between negtaive samples diverge to infinity. That would be an overkill and most likely the model will not be able to learn a meaningful representation.

Like you said here,

> Let say, if Y is 1 and distance value is larger, the first part become
> zero (1-Y), and second also become zero, because it should choose
> whether m-d or 0 is bigger. So the loss is zero which does not make
> sense. Can you please help me to understand this

The loss is zero when the distance is larger than m for negative samples. Thus, the model will not be further updated for negative pairs that it is already good at distinguishing.

Comment: thanks, this explanation make my confusion clear.